# Traduction du terme grammatical anglais « collocation »

Tags: anglais, terminologie, linguistique

On trouve en français le terme « collocation » en linguistique et il est défini comme suit,

> Emploi d'un terme relativement à d'autres, toutes variantes morphologiques confondues, et sans égard à la classe grammaticale », (« fruit » avec « manger », « doux» , « mûr », etc.)

ce qui n'est pas, spécifiquement, « a combination of words in a language that happens very often and more frequently than it would if only by chance », comme par exemple : *bitter tears* (plutôt que *sour tears*), *crying shame*, *weather permitting* (plutôt que *weather allowing*).

L'acception du terme anglais n'est pas sur la base de la sémantique (le fruit est quelque chose qui se mange) mais sur la base de l'usage, comme on peut le comprendre à partir des exemples.

Y aurait-il quelqu'un qui sache si ce concept est identifié dans la grammaire du français et quel est le mot correspondant?

Comment: Dans mon expérience, l'emploi qui en est fait en linguistique correspond à la définition anglophone que tu cite. D'où vient l'autre définition ?

Comment: **Colligation** (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi82Jjm_endAhUJbBoKHd0EAHoQFjAAegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.openedition.org%2Fcorpus%2Fpdf%2F2202&usg=AOvVaw2QbOzHF1sP4Lbdgtln_srq )

Comment: @Evpok Elle vient du TLFi: b) LING. Emploi d'un terme relativement à d'autres, toutes variantes morphologiques confondues, et sans égard à la classe grammaticale. Les noms de fruit comme pomme, orange, poire, pêche (...) se trouvent en collocation fréquente avec dessert, manger, doux, fruit, etc. (HALLIDAY, Ét. de ling. appliquée, t. 1, 1962, p. 22). Il n'existe pas de nom selon ce dictionnaire pour la combinaison dont les éléments se trouvent en collocation.

Answer (score 2):

Sans faute de ma part, en lisant les lemmes [français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_(linguistique)) et [anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) de wikipedia je ne vois pas aucune différence entre les emplois anglophone et francophone. En allemand aussi le terme est presque le même : [Kollokation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kollokation).

Voici quelques sources francophones pertinentes provenant d'une enquête rapide :

https://correspo.ccdmd.qc.ca/index.php/document/la-lecture-dans-tous-ses-etats/les-collocations-des-combinaisons-de-mots-privilegiees/ (Canada)

https://www.cairn.info/revue-langages-2013-1-page-47.htm#

https://www.uebersetzung-morlot.de/collocation-cooccurrence/

https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_2006_num_150_2_6850

https://gerflint.fr/Base/Espagne3/ana.pdf

http://www.tonitraduction.net/

https://books.openedition.org/septentrion/14551?lang=en

Il me semble que le terme collocation est utilisé de la même manière en linguistique française qu'en linguistique anglaise.

Answer (score 1):

Comme Dimitris l'affirme, je cite le dictionnaire anglais:

*collocation
/kɒləˈkeɪʃ(ə)n/
noun*

*1.LINGUISTICS
the habitual juxtaposition of a particular word with another word or words with a frequency greater than chance.*

Answer (score 0):

As links provided by Dimitris (repeated below) tend to prove the currently accepted term is "collocation";

https://www.cairn.info/revue-langages-2013-1-page-47.htm#

https://www.uebersetzung-morlot.de/collocation-cooccurrence/

The initial definition of the term, that is

- "([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/collocation)) b) LING. Emploi d'un terme relativement à d'autres, toutes variantes morphologiques confondues, et sans égard à la classe grammaticale. Les noms de fruit comme pomme, orange, poire, pêche (...) se trouvent en collocation fréquente avec dessert, manger, doux, fruit, etc. (HALLIDAY, Ét. de ling. appliquée, t. 1, 1962, p. 22)."

has very apparently been abandonned and the term "collocation" as initially coined (at least 1962) has been replaced by the term "cooccurrence", probably under the influence of the English. Incidentally, this latter term was about to be defined as having the meaning the French linguists appear  to give it presently; this can be elicited from the following definition of the TLFi.

- ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cooccurrence))  2. Co-occurrence, cooccurrence, subst. fém., ling. Apparition simultanée de deux ou plusieurs éléments ou classes d'éléments dans le même discours; p. méton., ces mêmes éléments. Telle pourrait être notre nouvelle définition de la co-occurrence: une suite d'enchevêtrements à probabilité infime (P. LAFON, M. TOURNIER, Une Nouvelle approche lexicométrique des cooccurrences dans un texte ds Travaux de lexicométrie et de lexicol. pol., nov. 1978, p.137).

The term "collocation" will then be ambiguous in the early research papers since it will be synonymous to "cooccurrence" as "cooccurrence" was defined initially, which definition has remained valid to the present day.

The article obtained from the second link makes clear that a collocation is a sort of cooccurrence.

- *On confond souvent les termes « collocation » et « cooccurrence », pourtant ils se distinguent. Le mot « collocation » vient du latin collocatio, qui signifie « disposition », et collocare, « placer ensemble ». À partir de là, on pourrait définir la collocation comme étant l’« arrangement des mots ». En fait, une collocation est une cooccurrence privilégiée.*